# PhpStorm function that change double quotes to single quotes in string

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I'm looking for a function in PhpStorm that transform the string like:

```
echo "my string: $var1, $var2, $var3";
```

into something like that:

```
echo 'my string: '.$var1.', '.$var2.', '.$var3';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use notepad replace all though

Comment: Use `Sublime-Text`  or in PHPStorm have to do it manually ;)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to want this? Hm, for future reference, of course...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The function needs also to distinct variables and add them to string via .(dot) operator. Not just change " to '.
The reason is making script running a little bit faster.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R to search and replace

Comment: Note that there are some tests out there that show the difference is negligible. This choice is often based on visual, such as when using HTML or based on IDE highlighting.

Comment: @PoliAkustyczny - if this is purely for speed, then you won't even be able to measure the difference in execution.... if for reasons of readability, then ensure that it really is more readable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Install **"PHP 1Up!" plugin** and restart IDE.
2. Now you will have new intention available (accessible via <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or via light bulb icon):

[image]

**UPDATE 2022-12-28:**

The similar functionality is now implemented in PhpStorm itself (for a few years now). The intention is called **"Convert string interpolation to concatenation"**. The downside is it will not replace double quotes into single, this will have to be handled separately.

[image]

Although I personally highly prefer **"Convert string interpolation to a 'sprintf()' call"** one instead -- why use concatenation at all for such a stuff? Any kind of templating is always better (especially for making edits in the future):

- easier to add more stuff;
- easier to wrap those variables into a function calls (e.g. escaping/cleanup/formatting etc);
- easier to make translations (if needed of course);
- the string (template) can be taken from elsewhere (a config file/DB) etc.).

Sure, `sprintf()` is slower than just an `echo` with a bunch of concatenations, but it is much more convenient to use.

[image]

The result of the above:

```php
echo sprintf("my string: %s, %s, %s", $var1, $var2, $var3);
```

---

As others have already mentioned:

- no noticeable speed gains
- for *possibly better* readability, surround variables with `{}`, e.g. `echo "my string: {$var1}, {$var2}, {$var3}";`

Comment: Thank you, very much! This is what I was looking for.
I also consider using provided method by other users.

Comment: This no longer works. It was last update 8 years ago (source: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7577-php-1up- ). But now there is a native intention (or so I think), where you can make a text and click `Alt` + `Enter` and do some things. You can mark a line. You can also 'just' put the cursor in the middle of a double-quoted string and click `Alt`+`Enter` and then you'll get some options.

Comment: @Zeth The IDE has a similar functionality built-in now (not exact but quite close). See my edit. `Alt+Enter` in the same shortcut as before to bring that Quick Fix / Intentions menu.

Answer (score 16):

First we have to do a little phpstorm setup.

**Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys**
Please mark this. "Surround selection on typing quote or brace"

Click OK.

Then select the entire code with double quotes. Now press the single quotation key.

Done.

Comment: It won't unqoute and concatenate the variables like @PoliAkustyczny wanted if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

No way. You can explode it in concatenation by hands and then convert quotes:

1. With internal 'Replace quotes' action
2. Regexp find/replace
3. [String manipulation plugin](https://github.com/krasa/StringManipulation)